# In Rust, why does std::iter::Iterator's min function return a reference?

Tags: reference, rust, iterator, min

In Rust, why does std::iter::Iterator's [min](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min) function return a reference?

Take this example from the documentation page linked above:

```rust
let a = vec![1, 2, 3];

assert_eq!(a.iter().min(), Some(&1));
```

Why is the result a reference to the value `1` wrapped inside the Option type instead of the literal value `1`?  This little detail tripped me up recently.  I found I had to dereference the result after unwrapping it before I could use it in math operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it does not: `min()` returns an `Option<Self::Item>` where `Self` is the Iterator. That is, `min()` returns whatever the iterator yields. Since the iterator is created via `.iter()` on the `Vec`, you get an Iterator over references, therefore `min()` returns a reference. If you use `a.into_iter().min()` you get an owned value.

Your question suggests you wondered about the `Option` as well: The iterator may not yield any items at all. In this case, `min()` has no value and `None` is returned.

Comment: Note that `a.into_iter()` takes ownership of `a`. For integer values, you can also get an owned value with [`a.iter().copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) which allows you to keep using `a` afterwards.